# Possible to repair Raspberry Pi 3 SD card slot?

Tags: pi-3, hardware, sd-card

I accidentally pulled the pi out of the case before realizing the SD card was still attached. The right pad can still be soldered but the left one appears to have been pulled off. Is there anything I can do?

[image]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the metal sheath on a micro SD socket is just there as a mechanical guide - it's not electrically important for the card itself. The contact pins that sit underneath the card on the PCB look intact from your photo. I think I'd try to solder it back down as flat as is humanly possible and give it a test.

Comment: When I plug in the SD card and hold it in place with my thumb, I can feel a great amount of heat emanating from the left side of the cover. The rpi-3 LED glows solid red. No display via HDMI.

Comment: Ouch. That does sound fairly bad. What happens if you power the Pi without an SD card in it? Obviously it's not going to boot, but if you experience the same heat it would suggest that maybe there's damage beyond just the SD card socket.

Comment: I think you are likely to be a candidate for an tag:rip 8-).  When you say _"I can feel a great amount of heat emanating from the left side of the cover."_ do you mean the black outer cover for the MicroSD card that has been "ripped-up" in the above photo or do you mean in the area around where "F1" is in the bottom left corner of the picture or somewhere else?  If it is F1 then you probably have a damaged track that is shorting out a power line and the "polyfuse" that is F1 has tripped - which in this situation is __not__ a good sign...

Comment: ... a picture from the other direction onto the card holder (so that "160511E" can be seen the right way around, might show whether that casing on the card holder is shorting out any of the pins of it when it is bent up, if that happened only for a short while whilst the RPi was powered up that could trip the polyfuse (or damage the RPi) and a tripped fuse can take some time (hours?) to reset even after you remove the short by bending the case back down to the circuit board and remove the power.

Comment: I came today here for the same problem. It seems the analysis with the polyfuse was correct in my case. Apart from the bent slot I had the sd card cracked which probably caused the thing to heat up. I tried with a good card and nothing happened; then after a while probably the polyfuse was reset, and it was possible again to boot.

Comment: When this happened, I think the SD card went bad somehow, hence I was feeling heat when I touched it (testing on laptop confirmed this) .. I tried a different card and Pi was able to read ok. Overall the Pi was not disabled, I used a little hot glue to seat the cover and all works well now.